# How to Solve this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product_stocks')?

Tags: javascript, laravel

This is vue part:

```
**<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm" role="form" method="post">
 <div class="row">
     <show-error></show-error>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Stock Manage</h5><br>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Product <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                             <select  @change="selectedProduct" class="form-control" v-model="form.product_id">
                                 <option v-for="(item,index) in products" :key="index" :value="item.id" >{{item.name}}</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                  <div class="card-footer">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Submit</button>
                     </div>    
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title"> Product Size</h5>
                 <br>

                 <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr v-for="(item ,index) in form.items" :key="index">
                <td> {{ item.size}} </td>
                    <td>
                <input class="form-control" v-model="item.quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
                  </td>   
                  </tr>
                 </table>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>    
 </div>
    </form>    
</template>    
<script>
import store from '../../store'
import  * as actions from '../../store/action-types'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import ShowError from '../utils/ShowError'
  export  default {
    components: {ShowError},
       data() {
        return {
            form: {
               product_id: '',
                    items: [    
              ]
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            'products': 'getProducts',
                       })
    },   
    mounted() {

        //get PRODUCTS
        store.dispatch(actions.GET_PRODUCTS)           
    },
    methods: {

            selectedProduct(id){

             let product = this.products.filter(product=>product.id ==id)
                product[0].product_stocks.map(stock=>{
                 let item ={
                size : stock.size.size,
                size_id : stock.size_id,
              quantity : ''
             }
            
             this.form.items.push(item)

             })
   
            }            
        }
     }        
</script>**
```

This is console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'product_stocks')
> at VueComponent.selectedProduct (app.js:2390)
> at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:24815)
> at HTMLSelectElement.invoker (app.js:25136)
> at HTMLSelectElement.original._wrapper (app.js:30543)

Please.... I have tried everything .A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `product[0]` does not include `product_stocks`. check `product[0]` before using it

Comment: I can not understand,
If you can help me this my any desk id-125 864 918

Comment: I am a React guy. I dont know vue.js

Comment: This has nothing to do with `vue.js` and is a vanilla JavaScript error. The result of your `products` `filter` is not what you expect.

Comment: Can you help me? How to write this function (selectedproduct).

Comment: You need to do some debugging, either `this.products` doesn't contain anything, or it doesn't contain a product with the `id` you're searching for.